# SQLite (Android) - Selecting Random Row

Tags: android, database, sqlite, random, cursor

I have a method to return a Cursor, however it unfortunately spawns a NullPointerException for some reason.

Here's the method, is there anything wrong with it?:

```
public Cursor getRandom(String tableName) {
        return db.query(tableName + " Order BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_TEXT}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: The only possibilities are tableName == null, KEY_ID == null or KEY_TEXT == null. Can you check those 3 in real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order by statement is in the wrong place.

```
SQLiteDatabase.query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit).
```

Take a look at the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Comment: So how could I fix the query to match this?

Comment: How did you tried this time? 
try this: `return db.query(tableName, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_TEXT}, null, null, null, null, "RANDOM()", "1");`

Comment: It says: HAVING clauses are only permitted when using a groupBy clause

Comment: I have tried: 

    `return db.query(tableName, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_TEXT}, null, new String[] {KEY_ID}, null, "RANDOM()", "1");`

AND:

    `return db.query(tableName, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_TEXT}, null, null, null, "RANDOM()", "1");`

Comment: And I get the error: `09-04 22:03:48.403: E/AndroidRuntime(29834): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HAVING clauses are only permitted when using a groupBy clause`

Comment: Haha, thank you. Now I get a different error though, any ideas with this one? `09-04 22:09:43.840: E/AndroidRuntime(30030): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1`

Comment: Please count the parameters according to the statement of the api. 
`SQLiteDatabase.query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit).`. You are missing the **null** arg before the **random()**. If you don't include it, it will be interpreted as `query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)`.

Comment: did you moved your cursor.moveToFirst();??

Comment: Wow! That worked! Why do we have to move the cursor to first? :)

Comment: So you can do `while(cursor.next()) { //... }` and be sure the code only executes if the `Cursor` contains data.

Comment: I meant `cursor.moveToNext()`. Sorry.