# how would I get a random rowId from my database?

Tags: android, sqlite, random

I have a database wherein i get my questions , correct answers/options from... I want my application to automatically generate random rowIds so that the questions could be shuffled.. Of course, the question that's already shown should not display again. I want to get 10 questions then finish();..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a random rowId is the wrong approach. What if the database is modified and the ID becomes invalid? You'd have to check every ID and regenerate when an invalid ID comes up.

Instead, you should use a LIMIT clause in your SELECT statement with a random number less than the number of rows in the table.

Comment: Also check out this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270802/sqlite-android-selecting-random-row

Answer (score 0):

No need to generate random ids first. Just insert your rows, making sure you have the `questionId` column.

When you want read your database. Do something like `quizid = rand()` ....

After that you select the row with quizid in your database

```
SELECT * FROM quiztable WHERE questionId = quizid
```

Something like that will give you a random row from your database.

I think you get the point.